# Could not use trait associated constants as an array length?

Tags: rust

consider the following trait:

```
trait Test {
    const COUNT: usize = 12;
    fn test() {
        let arr: [f32; Self::COUNT]; // doesn't work
        dbg!(Self::COUNT); // works
    }
}
```

`dbg!(Self::COUNT)` works fine but I can't declare an array with `[f32; Self::COUNT]`:

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `COUNT` found for type `Self` in the current scope
 --> src/lib.rs:4:24
  |
4 |         let arr: [f32; Self::COUNT];
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ associated item not found in `Self`
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
  = note: the following trait defines an item `COUNT`, perhaps you need to implement it:
          candidate #1: `Test`
```

However this works in global constants:

```
const G_COUNT: usize = 1;
const G_ARR: [i32; G_COUNT] = [1]; // works
```

Is there a way to use trait associated constants like global constants?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ee1098f20f23b5c7cca0bb88d38a887)

Comment: It's not possible in this context, because array size can't be share between all implementations of trait `Test` that could compile one day but not now. Use a vector or do not use default implementation.

Comment: This is a known issue, covered by the duplicate and [Rust issue #42863](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42863).

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the info